# How can I simulate a DAG 401k contribution transaction?

Tags: yodlee

I have sample XML transactions for "buy" and "sell", but Yodlee provides many, many, many different type of transactions. What XML should I use to simulate a 401k contribution transaction?

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely check with Yodlee Support team and ask them to share an xml which may have some more details and you can use the same under your DAG. This will allow you to test such transactions for that specific type of accounts.